# Excel VBA: Obtain the Column and Row of current element in "For Each" loop

Tags: excel, vba, foreach

I am fairly new to VBA Excel Macros and I probably misunderstood something.

I am trying to extract the range (as in "A1", "A2", etc) of the element "rng" that is looping in a For Each loop, but instead I am getting its cell value.
I assumed **VBA.Interaction.MsgBox prompt:=rng** would return the range value of the active cell too, but not.

I simplified the code but the intention is to save in a array the location of cells ("A1", "A2", etc) matching a criteria for further processing.

How do I extract the column and row indexes of rng in a For Each loop?

Thanks

```
Sub test()
    Dim rng As Range 
    
    For Each rng In Range("A1:A10")
        rng.Value = rng.Value + 10
        VBA.Interaction.MsgBox prompt:=rng ' this gives me 10, 10,... instead of "A1", "A2"....
    Next rng
End Sub
```

Comment: `rng.Address(False, False)`?

Comment: This sounds like an XY problem. *"the intention is to save in a array the location of cells ("A1", "A2", etc) matching a criteria for further processing"* ---> I'd use `Union` here.

Comment: @BigBen, yeah, Msgbox rng.Address(False, False) gets me the result I want. Cheers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MsgBox rng.Address(RowAbsolute:=False, ColumnAbsolute:=False )